# I can't target positioned elements uniquely with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am working on a project, I pool image src from database and keeps it hidden until a button relative to the location of the image is clicked. However, the image is positioned absolutely. Below is my code segments.

HTML

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
             <th>S/N</th>
             <th>Name</th>
             <th>Phone</th>
             <th>Proof of Payment</th>
             <th>Activate User</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

        <tr> 
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Okolo Michael</td>
            <td>08062970094</td>
            <td><button class="btn btn-warning view_pop">View POP</button></td>
            <td><button class="btn btn-primary">Activate User</button></td>
            <div class="pop_view"><img src="pop/59a178206fade2.43644948.jpg" alt="File not Found"> <span class="close">X</span></div>
           </tr><tr> 
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Okeke Chidimma</td>
            <td>08044323123</td>
            <td><button class="btn btn-warning view_pop">View POP</button></td>
            <td><button class="btn btn-primary">Activate User</button></td>
            <div class="pop_view"><img src="pop/59a178206fade2.43644948.jpg" alt="File not Found"> <span class="close">X</span></div>
          </tr><tr> 
            <td>3</td>
            <td>Anibueze Chigozie</td>
            <td>08162657108</td>
            <td><button class="btn btn-warning view_pop">View POP</button></td>
            <td><button class="btn btn-primary">Activate User</button></td>
           <div class="pop_view"><img src="pop/59a178206fade2.43644948.jpg" alt="File not Found"> <span class="close">X</span></div>
          </tr> </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

JQuery

```
$('.view_pop').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().siblings('.pop_view').css('display', 'block');
    $(this).html('Viewed');
});

$('.close').click(function() {
    $(this).parent('.pop_view').css('display', 'none');
});
```

CSS

```
.pop_view{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 5;
    top: 25%;
    left: 25%;

}

.close{
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

When the button is clicked, the image doesn't show. How do I select these images uniquely based on the clicked button?

Comment: A DIV is not a valid child of a TR, so the browser moves it, and it's no longer the sibling, and the code fails

Comment: @MichaelOkolo  did you checked the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually a `<div>` inside `<tr>` is invalid structure, and browser rendered it on top (outside of whole table itself), that's why your code failed (because it's no-more `child/siblings` of `tr/td`).

Solution:- convert `<div>`  to `<td>`

***Working example:-***

```js
$('.view_pop').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().siblings('.pop_view').css('display', 'block');
    $(this).html('Viewed');
});

$('.close').click(function() {
    $(this).parent('.pop_view').css('display', 'none');
});
```

```css
.pop_view{
display:none;
float:left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
<thead>
  <tr>
       <th>S/N</th>
       <th>Name</th>
       <th>Phone</th>
       <th>Proof of Payment</th>
       <th>Activate User</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

  <tr> 
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Okolo Michael</td>
      <td>08062970094</td>
      <td><button class="btn btn-warning view_pop">View POP</button></td>
      <td><button class="btn btn-primary">Activate User</button></td>
      <td class="pop_view"><img src="pop/59a178206fade2.43644948.jpg" alt="File not Found"> <span class="close">X</span></td>
     </tr><tr> 
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Okeke Chidimma</td>
      <td>08044323123</td>
      <td><button class="btn btn-warning view_pop">View POP</button></td>
      <td><button class="btn btn-primary">Activate User</button></td>
      <td class="pop_view"><img src="pop/59a178206fade2.43644948.jpg" alt="File not Found"> <span class="close">X</span></td>
    </tr><tr> 
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Anibueze Chigozie</td>
      <td>08162657108</td>
      <td><button class="btn btn-warning view_pop">View POP</button></td>
      <td><button class="btn btn-primary">Activate User</button></td>
     <td class="pop_view"><img src="pop/59a178206fade2.43644948.jpg" alt="File not Found"> <span class="close">X</span></td>
    </tr> </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much... This pretty much solved the problem. I learnt a lot from this. I upvoted though it cant show up here since am new to this community but I am indebted. Thanks @AlivetoDie

Comment: OK, Done that. Thanks